# Jquery Find first direct child of a type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am looking for a way to find the first direct child of an element, of a precise type.

Let's imagine this markup:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="otherDiv">
        <p> Stuff </p>
    </div>
    <p> Stuff 2 </p>
    <p> Stuff 3 </p>
</div>
```

So here, what I want to get is "Stuff 2" the first paragraph to be a direct child.

If using jquery I do something like `$('#mainDiv').find('p:first');` I will get the paragraph inside the first div.

What I need is to ignore nested childs and take only the first direct one. How should I do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the direct descendant selector `>`

```
$('#mainDiv > p:first')
```

or even `children()`

```
$('#mainDiv').children('p').first()
```

Comment: I would rather use standard CSS form here: `$('#mainDiv > p:first-child')`. So it will use native `document.querySelect()` implementation directly.

Comment: @c-smile - but the first paragraph isn't the first child, so that would fail.

Comment: @adeneo, I am reading this "the first direct child of an element, of a precise type" as exactly this condition `p:first-child`

Comment: @c-smile - And you would be wrong, `p:first-child` gets a paragraph that is the first child of it's parent, so for the posted markup it would fail as the div is the first child. For the first element of it's type we use a selector and `:first` to get the first element in the collection.

Comment: @adeneo let's try to get that phrase literally:
"the first direct child of an element" - that is `> *:first-child` precisely. And ", of a precise type" I am reading as "and of precise type". And so the final condition is `> type:first-child`.

Comment: @c-smile - you just keep on arguing, why don't you just try it -> http://jsfiddle.net/SQA2S/ and see that first-child ***only*** selects an element that is the first child of the parent element, it does not select elements that are first of it's type, so your selector would return nothing in this case.

Comment: @c-smile, @adeneo is correct in this case. however, replacing `:first-child` with `:first-of-type` works perfectly for the purpose and is, indeed, faster