# Remove first img in first li element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html like this

```
<ul class="products">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="product-images">
            <span class="featured-image">
                <img src="img1.jpg"/>
                <img src="img1-1.jpg"/>

            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="product-images">
             <span class="featured-image">
                <img src="img2.jpg"/>
                <img src="img2-2.jpg"/>
             </span>
        </a>            
    </li>

//some other li elements
</ul>
```

What I want to do is get the **fist** image in the **first li** element and remove that with jQuery.

*What I've tried*

```
jQuery (document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.products li:first .featured-image img:first').remove();
});
```

But that removes all img under first span.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: There's a superfluous `)` in your selector

Comment: ...and you want `.featured-image:first img`. Otherwise you'll select the first image in each `.featured-image` element.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117483/jquery-find-first-direct-child-of-a-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531189/jquery-first-of-type-selector

Comment: Editted my question @Pekka웃

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select first `li` and then find first `img` inside it and remove it [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1443/).

```
$('.products li').first().find('img').first().remove()
```

Another way to do this is

```
$('.products li:first img:first').remove()
```

Comment: Editted my question

Comment: But that removes all img elements under first span.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, where I look for the first *direct child* `img` of the first `.featured-image` element

```
jQuery (document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.featured-image:first > img:first').remove();
});
```

Comment: But that removes all img elements under first span @Alex

Comment: Uhm... no, it doesn't. http://jsbin.com/gudadujuwe/edit?html,js,output Try taking in and out the second `:first`