# Remove image inside a table using its coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***Problem***

how to correctly remove an image with jquery/javascript using its coordinate?

***Pen***

[Here the pen](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/MqYarz)

***Code and explanation***

I declared one global array of objects

```
const items=[
    {
        name: "axe",
        image: "https://image.ibb.co/n1hTEe/icons8_small_axe_64.png",
        hit: 3,
        actualPosition: {
            row: 0,
            cell: 0
        }
    },

    {   
        name: "scythe", 
        image: "https://image.ibb.co/nqpJ2z/if_holidays_scythe_1459435.png",
        hit: 4,
        actualPosition: {
            row: 0,
            cell: 0
        }    
    },

    {
        name: "sword",
        image: "https://image.ibb.co/jXzuLK/icons8_sword_48.png",
        hit: 2,
        actualPosition: {
            row: 0,
            cell: 0
        }     
    },
```

With the function below is possible to " catch " an object, the relative image of the object will appear in the top-right box of player one,in the right side near the text

```
<p>Health:</p>
<p>Mana:</p>
```

if the character and the object have the same coordinates, the characters will have the relative bonus of the objects and we will launch the function to remove the image (and the coordinates) of the object from the map.

```
function catchAnObjects(){

    let rowChar = character.actualPosition.row,
        cellChar = character.actualPosition.cell,
        itemRow = 0,
        itemCell = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){

        itemRow = items[i].actualPosition.row;
        itemCell = items[i].actualPosition.cell;

        if(itemRow === rowChar && itemCell === cellChar){
            character.hit = character.hit + items[i].hit;
            $("#itemPlayerOne").attr("src",items[i].image);
            removeItem(items[i]);
            break;
        };
    };
};
```

The object has to disappear from the map but not from the character's div, so I tried this,

```
function removeItem(item){
    let coord=item.actualPosition; 
    var itemImage = $(item.name);
    var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
    var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
    var tile = $(".tile", cell);  
    tile.remove(itemImage);
};
```

but it doesn't works, I can pick the object but I cannot delete the one from the map. How can I achieve this ?

The map is a 2d array random generated, something like this:

```
map = [[1,1,1,1,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,1,1,1],
       [1,0,0,0,1],
       [1,1,1,0,1]]
```

any advice will be really appreciated, thanks.

***UPDATE***

I think that the problem is in the function below.

what I want to do to fix it, or try to is:

select the elements in the position coord.row, coord.cell.
select the image with the proper item.name and remove it.

```
function removeItem(item){
    let coord=item.actualPosition; 
    var itemImage = $(item.name);
    var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
    var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
    var tile = $(".tile", cell);  
    tile.remove(itemImage);
}
```

So I will put this function in a comment before delete it, right now I'm trying to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it isn't be the best answer, and in this case any kind of correction will be really appreciated (i really need to learn) but i find a solution to this.

```
function removeItem(item){
    let coord=item.actualPosition; 
    var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
    var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
    var tile = $(".tile", cell);
    tile.first().find('img').first().remove();
};
```

i achieved this answer thanks to this post:

1)[Remove first img in first li element with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697141/remove-first-img-in-first-li-element-with-jquery)